# Alternative to FOR Loop for below

Tags: r, for-loop

I have written a for loop that takes a group of 5 rows from a dataframe and passes it to a function, the function then returns just one row after doing some operations on those 5 rows. Below is the code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(features_data1)){
  if (i - start == 4){
    group = features_data1[start:i,]
    group <- as.data.frame(group)
    start <- i+1
    sub_data = feature_calculation(group)
    final_data = rbind(final_data,sub_data)
  }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest me an alternative to this as the for loop is taking a lot of time. The function feature_calculation is huge.

Comment: Try to first create a vector containing groups (tip: `rep(1:ngroups, each=5)` then have a look at `tapply`

Comment: The speed of the for loop probably isn't what's holding you back. try optimising the `feature_calculation()` function, and allocate `final_data` before the loop instead of growing it each time - this involves copying the whole object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for a base R approach:

```
# convert features to data frame in advance so we only have to do this once
features_df <- as.data.frame(features_data1)

# assign each observation (row) to a group of 5 rows and split the data frame into a list of data frames 
group_assignments <- as.factor(rep(1:ceiling(nrow(features_df) / 5), each = 5, length.out = nrow(features_df)))
groups <- split(features_df, group_assignments)

# apply your function to each group individually (i.e. to each element in the list)
sub_data <- lapply(X = groups, FUN = feature_calculation)

# bind your list of data frames into a single data frame
final_data <- do.call(rbind, sub_data)
```

You might be able to use the purrr and dplyr packages for a speed-up. The latter has a function `bind_rows` that is much quicker than `do.call(rbind, list_of_data_frames)` if this is likely to be very large.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks. Its reduced the time.